# Using sqlite to analyse apache logs

Tags: sql, apache, sqlite

I am using the [asql package](http://www.steve.org.uk/Software/asql/) (sqlite) to analyse apache log files. I am trying to run a query that returns [distinct IP addresses] [authenticated user] [number of times that user has authenticated from that ip address]

The query that nearly works but does not include counts is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(source), user FROM logs ORDER BY user
```

but as soon as to add COUNT(*) I get one line returned. If I try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(source), user, COUNT(*) FROM logs GROUP BY user
```

I cannot see where one user has authenticated from multiple IPs. I'm new to sql and not sure if I need to use an alias or a nested count query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to include `source` in the `group by`.

```
SELECT source, user, COUNT(*)
FROM logs
GROUP BY source, user ;
```

`DISTINCT` is not a function.  There is a clause in SQL that is `SELECT DISTINCT` and the `DISTINCT` applies to all columns, regardless of parentheses.